# Generate a html file from java

Tags: java, html

This java code has output a html code, to generate a final result I need copy/paste and save filex.html.

How can I write this code to generate a report.html file in C:/ ?

System.out.println(html);

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\report.html");
out.print(html);
```